# Can a strong nucleophile carry out an SN1 reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

For example, if I take a tertiary halide in water + ethanol solution and add I- ions to it (which is a good nucleophile), then shouldn't the reaction be SN1; because SN2 is not possible as the substrate is tertiary. Please explain.

Comment: http://11452-presscdn-0-51.pagely.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/compare-sn1sn2.png

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've pretty much said it all already. SN2 is ruled out at the tertiary centre. Since the attack of the nucleophile in the SN1 mechanism is not rate-determining, it doesn't matter whether the nucleophile is weak or strong; iodide works fine.

In this case, it's more likely to get intercepted by the *solvent* itself, which is present in much larger quantities and is also nucleophilic, but that's another story.

Comment: So basically it would be SN1 but it would form alcohol instead of iodide.

Comment: @DHMO Yes, indeed. It'll either give the alcohol or the ethyl ether.